# Chamada de Future com tipo Void

Tags: java, thread

**Situação**

Precisava imprimir um relatório em pdf através um método void que retornava o response e após a impressão em tela se tornava necessário invalidar a chave de permissão diretamente no banco.

**Problema**

Logo após a chamada da impressão, a chave era invalidada no banco sem dar tempo de imprimir o relatório. Realizei tentativas com thread sleep, mas em sucesso.

**Solução**
Criar um Future e aguardar a finalização da Thread para então atualizar o banco.

**Implementação**

```
            String chave = req.getParameter("chave");
            final HttpServletResponse respFuture = resp;
            final Map paramFuture = param;
            final String jasperPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/jasper/rendimentosCopart/rendimentosCopart.jasper");

            try {
                param.put("P_CHAVE", chave);
                param.put("REPORT_LOCALE", new Locale("pt","BR"));
                // Gerando relatório

                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

                Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws Exception {
                        try{
                            createPDFReport(respFuture, paramFuture, jasperPath, "rendimentosCopart.pdf");
                        } catch (ReportException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });

                while (!future.isDone()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                future.get();
                executor.shutdown();
                RelatoriosRhevDelegate.invalidaChave(chave);
            } catch (Exception e){
                IRelatoriosRhev.LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
```

Comment: Tá, mas qual a dúvida?

Comment: O método [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) do Future já deve esperar terminar a execução, acho que você não precisa do while em cima desse get.

Comment: Uma coisa que não entendi. Se você está executando a impressão em uma thread separada, isso quer dizer que o método `createPDFReport()` é bloqueante. Se ele é bloqueante, você poderia muito bem chamá-lo diretamente (sem precisar de executor) e em seguida invalidar a chave. Por que não pode fazer isso?

Comment: Se ele não é bloqueante, não faz sentido chamá-lo em uma thread separada.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade nesse caso o problema era outro, eu pensei que devido ao createPDFReport disparar o response, o método que invalidava a chave estava executando antes do response chegar ao navegador. Porém descobri que o problema só ocorria no Edge, esse navegador estranhamente faz 2 requests para imprimir o pdf, e no primeiro já invalidava a chave.

Para solucionar :

```
String userAgent = req.getHeader("user-agent");
createPDFReport(resp, param, jasperPath, "rendimentosCopart.pdf");
if(userAgent.contains("Edge")){
        String dlnaHeader = req.getHeader("getcontentfeatures.dlna.org");
        if(dlnaHeader != null)
            RelatoriosRhevDelegate.invalidaChave(chave);
```